# what's the difference between classic text and TLF text

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, tlf, flashcatalyst

what's the difference between classic text and TLF text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=the+difference+between+classic+text+and+TLF+text

http://forums.adobe.com/message/2913998

[SNIP - Link MIA]

Comment: I agree that the answer to this question is easily available if one use Google; but if you don't have the time or patience to write up an answer here, I think you should just leave the links as a comment instead of an _answer_ - that's what I've seen being done so far in SO. Just saying.

Comment: How would copy-pasting what they said and taking credit for it be any more helpful? So I put an editorial on my posts to let people know how they can find knowledge for themselves.. that's added-value. It answers the question - so it's an answer.

Comment: Were it not for SO etiquette and community standards I'd just go with STFW. It's what I'd tell any developer under me if they asked. It teaches (well, forces) initiative - but let's not get into that debate. That's not what I did. I answered the question and made it pretty darn clear how I did it too. No crime in that, surely?

Comment: @Rushyo +1 you took the time to find the answers and give the links @Amarghosh the quality of the answer mirrors the quality of the question

Comment: I remember reading somewhere (in meta, iirc) that mere links are better posted as comments in SO. And I didn't mean you should copy paste and take the credit; I said post it as a comment and don't take the credit (the rep). That said, personally I don't care if you earn some rep from this one - after all you did a search, and didn't post a lmgtfy link. Btw, I like how you said STFU from within the etiquette of SO and community standards. @Patrick I believe comment notifications are done only for the first @ reference in a comment.

Comment: @Amarghosh I wasn't actually aware that @ had special significance. Something new every day :]

Comment: One problem with an answer like this is that those links will sooner or later get outdated and so this "answer" has much less value. For instance, the third link you pasted doesn't land on an article, but rather the main blog listing for gskinner.com

Comment: True. That's why there were multiple links. I mean, I could just steal other people's work and place it here under a CC license - but that tends to be frowned upon. I could rewrite what they put in my own words. Then I'd be wasting my time, delaying the answer and inviting inaccuracies. I could save the files onto my server, but then my server could get struck by lightning. I didn't think the question warranted a committee to perform a risk analysis on the potential options.

Comment: Though let's be honest, the real answer was Let Me Google That For You. But SO have, not unreasonably, blocked that.

Answer (score 3):

Most important differences between Classic and TLF fields

- TLFs support right-to-left text (hebrew, arabic, etc), classics do not
- TLFs can be formatted extensively, they have a lot of rich text features
- You can't use classic embedded fonts for TLFs, the need their own format
- TLFs support multi-column text
- Initial formatting: The inner paddings differ when you create TLF/Classic (Don't know by how much, that's why I came here, thanks, Rushyo, I would've never thought of visiting the Adobe page...)
- To use TLF in flash builder, you have to manually include tlfruntime.swc
- TLFs render text completely different, it's impossible to get the same appearance as with a classic TF. even with the exact same settings.
- TLFs are implemented via an ActionScript framework, not the Plugin. They have performance issues and are (officially) not recommended for use on mobile devices.

There are many more detailed differences for which you'd have to ask a more in-depth question or visit adobe's forums, but those are the basics.

Answer (score -1):

From Adobe at https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/classic-text.html retrieved 01/25/2017

Classic text is the name for the older text engine in Animate. The classic text engine is still available in CS5 and later. Classic text may be preferable for certain types of content, such as for mobile devices, where SWF file size must be kept to a minimum.

From Adobe at https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/text-layout-framework-tlf-text.html retrieved 01/25/2017

Beginning in Flash Professional CS5, you can add text to a FLA file using a new text engine called the Text Layout Framework (TLF). TLF supports a wider array of rich text layout features and fine control of text attributes. TLF text allows greater control of text than the previous text engine, now called Classic text.

Note: (Animate CC only) The Text Layout Framework is deprecated and the functionality will be unavailable with Animate CC. If a FLA file containing TLF Text, previously saved with an older version of Animate, is opened with Animate CC, then TLF is converted to Classic Text.

From me: Last night, I tried using TLF in a file I was going to edit on Flash CC and got an error message about it being deprecated.